# Getting uploaded file content with custom objects

Tags: android, quickblox-android

I know how to fetch Custom Objects but I have a ListView where I want to populate the text fields from the Custom Objects as well as the images for each record, I have a file UID saved for each record. Do I have to send up a separate request for each record for the Custom Object and Image(via file UID) or is there a way to request both items through one request efficiently?